# SAS format : full month name to integer

Tags: formatting, sas

what is the best to format full month name to integer in SAS?

'January' --> 1 
'February' --> 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this without a format:

```
data test;
  monthtext="January";
  month=month(input("01"||substr(monthtext,1,3)||"2000",date9.));
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own format:

```
options fmtsearch=(work);

proc format;
 invalue MonNum
   JANUARY = 1
   FEBRUARY = 2
   ;
run;

data Month;
 length month $10;
 input Month $;
 month=upcase(month);
 monthnum=input(month,monnum.);
 datalines;
  January
  February
  ;
 Run;

Proc report data=work.month nowd;
 column month monthnum;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using input function to convert character type to numerical type. But I will agree that creating custom format is better then.

```
data test;      
  input monthchar $15.;
  datalines;
  December
  January
  March
  ;
  run;

data test; 
  set test;
   monthnum=month(input(cats(1,substr(monthchar,1,3),2000),date9.)); 
  run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to use this in your code.  If you need to repeat this mapping in multiple sections of your code then I would suggest creating a custom format using PROC FORMAT which can be used in data steps or in other procedures.  If you are just doing this mapping in one data step, then you could use SELECT/WHEN or IF/ELSE IF logic to do the same.  There are many other ways to accomplish this in SAS, but I think these two methods are the most straight forward.